# Multiple actors linked to a shared database

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka, casbah

The constellation of `actor`s I am working with shares a hierarchical structure. Each of those actors needs to save data in a `mongodb` database. Rather than creating a link to the database for each actor, I thought it would be better if there was a method to inherit this aforementioned link from the top actor to its children.

Is there a way to do that in lieu of the actors inheriting the database name and rebuilding the link each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to create an actor (or pool of actors behind a router) who are responsible for communicating with the MongoDB, and have your other actors communicate their needs to that actor/pool.

Comment: What I did not say is that I encounter this error: `com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket`. After some researches, I found that my problem appears because of Linux seeing each connection as an open file (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419325/mongodb-insert-fails-due-to-socket-exception). Your alternative seems a good method to avoid increasing the os `limits`. Thanks.