# Zoomdata error - Connect to localhost:3333 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, apache-spark, connection, categories

Good morning.

I am an intern currently working on a proof of concept requiring me to use zoomdata to visualize data from elasticsearch on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I managed to connect both on docker - in short, each process ran in a separate, isolated container and communicated through ports -  but the performance wasn't good enough (the visualisation encountered bugs for files > 25 mb).

So I decided to install zoomdata on my computer (trial, .deb version)
I also installed mongodb first.

However, when I run zoomdata, I have two issues, and I believe that solving the second might solve the first:
-the first is that when I create a new elasticsearch connexion, I enter exactly the same parameters as with docker (I've triple checked, they are accurate):

> node name: elasticsearch (the name of my node)
>
> client type : HTTP node
>
> adress: 192.168.10.4  and port: 9200

-the second is when I run zoomdata:
During the initialisation (more accurately, the spark one) I have an error message (more details below):

> c.z.s.c.r.impl.CategoriesServiceClient   : Attempt: 1 to send
> categories registration failed. Connect to localhost:3333
> [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused

followed by the same message over and over again (the attempt number changes) as the rest of the program executes normally.

I took a look at the logs - computer(bug) and docker(works).
Note: the SAML error doesn't stop the docker version from working, so unless fixing it fixes other problems It's not my priority.

Computer:

> 2016-06-15 16:04:06.680 ERROR 1 --- [           main]
> c.z.core.service.impl.SamlService        : Error initializing SAML.
> Disabling SAML.
>
> 2016-06-15 15:58:12.125  INFO 8149 --- [           main]
> com.zoomdata.dao.mongo.KeyValueDao       : Inserting into key value
> collection com.zoomdata.model.dto.SamlConfig@4f3431a1
>
> 2016-06-15 15:58:12.789  INFO 8149 --- [           main]
> c.z.core.init.SystemVersionBeanFactory   : Server version 2.2.6,
> database version 2.2.6, git commit :
> 0403c951946e5daf03000d83ec45ad85d0ce4a56, built on 06060725
>
> 2016-06-15 15:58:17.571 ERROR 8149 --- [actory-thread-1]
> c.z.s.c.r.impl.CategoriesServiceClient   : Attempt: 1 to send
> categories registration failed. Connect to localhost:3333
> [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
>
> 2016-06-15 15:58:17.776 ERROR 8149 --- [actory-thread-1]
> c.z.s.c.r.impl.CategoriesServiceClient   : Attempt: 2 to send
> categories registration failed. Connect to localhost:3333
> [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
>
> 2016-06-15 15:58:18.537  INFO 8149 --- [           main]
> c.z.c.s.impl.SparkContextManager$2       : Running Spark version 1.5.1

Docker:

> 2016-06-15 16:04:06.680 ERROR 1 --- [           main]
> c.z.core.service.impl.SamlService        : Error initializing SAML.
> Disabling SAML.
>
> 2016-06-15 16:04:06.681  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> com.zoomdata.dao.mongo.KeyValueDao       : Inserting into key value
> collection com.zoomdata.model.dto.SamlConfig@43b09564
>
> 2016-06-15
> 16:04:07.209  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> c.z.core.init.SystemVersionBeanFactory   : Server version 2.2.7,
> database version 2.2.7, git commit :
> 97c9ba3c3662d1646b4e380e7640766674673039, built on 06131356
>
> 2016-06-15
> 16:04:12.117  INFO 1 --- [actory-thread-1]
> c.z.s.c.r.impl.CategoriesServiceClient   : Registered to handle
> categories: [field-refresh, source-refresh]
>
> 2016-06-15 16:04:12.427  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> c.z.c.s.impl.SparkContextManager$2       : Running Spark version 1.5.1

The server versions are different (2.2.6 for computer, 2.2.7 for docker) - I'll try to update the computer one but I don't have much hope that it will work.

What I tried already:

-use zoomdata as root: zoomdata refused, and internet told me why it was a bad idea to begin with.

-deactivate all firewalls : didn't do anything.

-search on the internet: didn't manage to solve.

I'm all out of ideas, and would be grateful for any assistance.

EDIT : I updated to 2.2.7, but the problem persists.
I'm wondering if there may be a problem with authorisations (since the connexion is refused).
I also tried disabling SSL on my zoomdata server.

EDIT: after a discussion on the [logs and .properties files seen here](https://gist.github.com/RMoulet/c1b6c49ac7121a38c1fa6dfbd453e3b3/)
the issue is the scheduler service not connecting to mongodb, although zoomdata does connect.
I filled the files following the [installation guide](http://docs.zoomdata.com/ubuntu-installation-steps-v2-2) but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs I see that scheduler cannot connect to mongo because socket exception. Found possible solution here: 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/15419325/mongodb-insert-fails-due-to-socket-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419325/mongodb-insert-fails-due-to-socket-exception)

> Comment out the line in your mongod.conf that binds the IP to 127.0.0.1. Usually, it is set to 127.0.0.1 by default. 
>   For Linux, this config file location should be be /etc/mongod.conf. 
>   Once you comment that out , it will receive connections from all interfaces. 
>   This fixed it for me as i was getting these socket exceptions as well.

Comment: Thank you I will try it when I'm finished with my current work.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. I've updated the Gist repository with the new scheduler log.

I am currently using Kibana for my visualisation needs, and will soon work with another person who has installed zoomdata on his computer - comparing the differences in our implementations will probably help me.